# Can i set the paths in tsconfig for multiple packages in a monorepo?

Tags: typescript, monorepo

I'm trying to setup a monorepo from scratch for learning purposes. It seemed to make sense to structure it like so. I installed a lot of dev dependencies in the root which seems to make sense since i did pull the packages out of a single repo, and it seems that I would have to repeat them all in each module.

Eslint and ts seem to play nicely if i use no aliases, however i would like to try to achieve this:

```
root/
├─ packages/
|  |
│  ├─ foo/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  |  ├─ a.ts
│  │  |  ├─ index.ts
│  │  |  ├─ nested/
│  │  |     ├─ b.ts
│  |  ├─ package.json
|  |
│  ├─ bar/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  |  ├─ index.ts
│  |  ├─ package.json
|  |
│  ├─ baz/
│     ├─ src/
│     |  ├─ index.ts
│     ├─ package.json
|
├─ tsconfig.json
├─ package.json
```

If I'm in a module, I want to use `~` for an absolute path "for that module":

```
// packages/foo/src/nested/b.ts

import {a} from '~/a'       //<-- want this
// import {a} from '../a'
```

If i import one onf my modules id like to distinguish it with an `@`

```
// packages/bar/src/index.ts

import {a} from '@foo'
```

I'm getting some weird results when playing with this, and at one point it seemed like eslint didn't like the paths that typescript started to understand.

How could i achieve this, or if i'm heading in the wrong direction what would be the right one? I believe i'm using yarn workspaces and nothing else. I'm not even building anything yet, i'm just trying to get vscode to play nicely with this.